# UINavigationBar and UITableView in Xcode 4.3.2

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Did you notice that UINavigationBar is not set anymore when creating a UITableView, even after giving it a title or a button?

Now i'm going mad on how to put a navigation bar over my UITableView. It seems really impossible. I tried to add to my tableView a subview with the Navigation Bar, but seems worthless, because when I scroll down, the navigation bar scrolls down as wellm and it shouldn't.

Any ideas on how to implement it?

**EDIT**

Well, as always I went on File -> New -> File.. -> UITableView. Then i set a bit of code and when I wrote

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"MyTitle";
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
```

and tried to test on Simulator, no Navigation Bar appeared.

My init code:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = @"TabTitle";
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"];
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor];

    }
    return self;
}
```

I can't explain why it doesn't appear anymore. I also tried to create a new project and import my classes from a project where the navigation bar appeared, but same result there too.

**EDIT2***

The app is a tabBased application.
Here is the code took from the App delegate used to set up the tabBar.

```
 UIViewController *viewController1, *viewController4;
    UITableViewController *viewController2, *viewController3;
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"First_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        viewController2 = [[Tips alloc] initWithNibName:@"Table" bundle:nil];
        viewController3 = [[Favorites alloc] initWithNibName:@"Test_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        viewController4 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Second_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    }
```

Comment: Well the UI is created via code, yes. I have 2 other UIViewController with UINavigationBar (but set via Interface Builder), but not into my tableView. I checked, and

Comment: Yes it's created via code. I have 2 other UIViewController with UINavigationBar correctly working (but set via IB). I checked, " navigationController is: (null)" .I have UINavigationControllerDelegate in my .h file.

Comment: Ok i think were getting close now ;) It seems that the controller is not on the navigationstack of the navbar. Can you post some code where you create the viewcontroller and push/animate it on screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initing an `UITabBarController` and set 4 `UIViewControllers` as the corresponding `UITabbarViewControllers`. Since two of them are normal `UIViewControntroller` and two are `UITableViewController` there can not be a navigation bar. You have to load the viewController where you'd like the navbar form a `UINavigationController`. The correct way would be (assuming vc3 is the one where you'd like the navbar):

```
UIViewController *viewController1, *viewController4;
UITableViewController *viewController2, viewController3;
UINavigationController *vc3NavController;
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"First_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    viewController2 = [[Tips alloc] initWithNibName:@"Table" bundle:nil];
    viewController3 = [[Favorites alloc] initWithNibName:@"Test_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    vc3NavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController3];        
    viewController4 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Second_iPhone" bundle:nil];
}
```

Then load the vc3NavController instead of viewController3 as the corresponding tab.
So you have: UITabBarController -> UINavigationController -> YourViewController

Maybe [Creating a Navigation Interface](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH2-SW27) will help you too.

Comment: Well, shouldn't it be `UINavigationController *vc3NavController;` ? And then     `vc3NavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController3];`  ?

Comment: Don't worry! But how can `vc3NavController` alloc itself? I mean, `vc3NavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]` and `vc3NavController = [[vc3NavController alloc]` are the same thing or?

Comment: you are again correct. but it seems you understand how it works and figured it out by yourself :D

Comment: Eheh it seemed a bit weird!  Thanks for the help though, really useful!!